# Unexpected output

Tags: php

I use the code to return data from a function and display it.

consider: `i = j = 0; count = 4;`

I do not get `4` return values from the code.. .which is expected output.

But i get the result when i replace the for loop with    `print_r($EODRow);`

Pls help.

```
    $i = 0; 

    $j = 0; 

    $count = getEODCount("A"); 

    for(; $i < $count; $i++)

    { 

          $EODRow = getEOD("A",$i); 

          print "<tr>"; 

          for(; $j < 12; $j++) 

          { 

                      print "<td>$EODRow[$j]</td>"; 

          }  

          print "</tr>";  

}
```

I return an array of values from the function.

Comment: please indent your code to make it more easy to read.

Comment: Don't declare the loop variables, `$i` and `$j` outside the for loops.  Declare them in the for loops, like `for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your loop variables each loop.  `$j` is not being reset to 0, after each `$i` loop.

You should really change your loops to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
```

and

```
for($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to reset $j back to 0 before the inner loop, since it will not output anything after the first run of the outer loop

Comment: This is likely the problem.  Otherwise only the first row will ever be printed...

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your variable with `{}`, so  `print "<td>{$EODRow[$j]}</td>";`

**Explanation:**

The problem is that the compiler wont apply the indexing to the $EODRow without you identifying that it's part of the same variable, which is what the `{}` are doing. (Well that's my understanding of the how/why anyway)

Comment: Then I can see this being a future issue you'll possibly run into

Answer (score 1):

try reseting $j to zero when another $i step is occured

```
 for(; $i < $count; $i++)

{ $j == 0;
```

Comment: Or just `for($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++)`